# Swapping Lebesgue integral and limit

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}; \lambda_m>0; lim_{m\to\infty}\lambda_m = 0;  \phi\in C([0, T]); f\in L_2([0, T])$.

Is it possible to exchange the following limit with the integration without further facts?

$$\int_0^T\int_0^T \lim\limits_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=N}^{M}\lambda_m\phi_m(t)f(t)\phi_m(s)f(s)dsdt$$

I am trying to establish that the  above equals $\sum\limits_{m>N}\lambda_m\langle f,\phi_m \rangle^2$, where $\langle ., .\rangle$ is the $L_2$ inner product. However,  I am unable to see conditions that would allow use of the (Lebesgue) Dominated or Monotone Convergence Theorems.

Purely for context, I am working through a proof of the *Mercer Representation Theorem*, and the $\lambda_m$ and $\phi_m$ are eigenvalules and eigenvectors of a compact self-adjoint operator. If the given facts are insufficient to swap the limit and integrals, this will confirms I need to reconsider how I've understood the [wider proof](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/1185/docs/MATH_606/MercerAndMore.pdf).

Many thanks.

*PS If someone has a link to a proof of the Mercer Representation Theorem that they're happy with, that would be appreciated also.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the given conditions are insufficient. After all $\operatorname{lim} \lambda_m \langle f, \phi_m \rangle^2$ should be $0$ whereas the integral might well be $\infty$. At least if you assume that $\phi_m$ be normed to $1$.

Comment: @BrunoKrams Apologies, this is my mistake. This should have been summation.  I've corrected above.